# How can I slice each 3x3 submatrix from an arbitrary size matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find each 3x3 submatrix from a bigger matrix. I'm stuck on how to slice each matrix without knowing the size of that matrix. If I know it is a 4x4 matrix, I can slice each submatrix one by one:

```
m = [[1, 5, 9, 2], 
     [0, 4, 6, 1], 
     [6, 1, 8, 8], 
     [4, 7, 3, 5]]

s1 = [m[0][:3], m[1][:3], m[2][:3]]

s1 = [[1, 5, 9], 
      [0, 4, 6], 
      [6, 1, 8]]
```

That is only the first 3x3 submatrix out of 4. The matrix can be 3x3, 4x3, 4x4, etc. all the way up to 10x10. Doing it manually for each is definitely out of the question. Is there a way for me to slice each 3x3 submatrix without knowing the size of the bigger matrix?

Comment: So you want `2x2` matrix of `3x3` matrices here?

Comment: I wanted to get all possible 3x3 matrices from a bigger matrix.

Comment: Yes but for this example there are four such submatrices? Or can there be submatrices where we for instance ignore the third row?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Imagine a convolving filter of size 3x3 going over this array. You'd have 4 windows, 4 different overlapping regions.

Comment: Are your input matrices (`m`) always going to be of same `width` than `height`? ( 4x4, 5x5...) or can you have 4x2?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: yes that was my initial idea as well. But "submatrix" is vague in the sense that `[[1,9],[0,6]]` is sometimes also considered a 2x2 submatrix of `m`. The first one scales linear with the number of elements in the matrix, the latter exponential.

Comment: The smallest matrix will always be 3x3 but bigger ones can be 4x3, 4x4, 5x4, etc. All the way up to 10x10. The submatrix has to be 3x3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrices are a bit confusing from a human point of view (erm... at least for *this human* who's answering **:-P**): when you do `m[1][2]`, the first `1` determines the *height* (the Y axis, if you may) rather than the *width* while the subsequent `2` determines the *width* (the X axis) which is not what we humans are used to.

With that in mind, you could do something like this (note that I changed the sample input `m` to a 6x5 matrix, just to make sure that a more generic case would work properly).

```
m = [[1, 5, 9, 2, 4, 7],
     [0, 4, 6, 1, 5, 7],
     [6, 1, 8, 8, 6, 8],
     [4, 7, 3, 5, 7, 9],
     [8, 9, 6, 3, 1, 1],
     ]

slice_x = 3
slice_y = 3


def test_slice():
    width = len(m[0])
    height = len(m)
    slices = []
    for i in range(0, height - slice_y + 1):
        for j in range(0, width - slice_x + 1):
            slices.append(
                [
                    [m[a][b] for b in range(j, j + slice_x)]
                    for a in range(i, i + slice_y)
                ]
            )
    return slices


if __name__ == "__main__":
    slices = test_slice()
    for sl in slices:
        for row in sl:
            print(row)
        print('------')
```

Outputs

```
[1, 5, 9]
[0, 4, 6]
[6, 1, 8]
------
[5, 9, 2]
[4, 6, 1]
[1, 8, 8]
------
[9, 2, 4]
[6, 1, 5]
[8, 8, 6]
------
[2, 4, 7]
[1, 5, 7]
[8, 6, 8]
------
[0, 4, 6]
[6, 1, 8]
[4, 7, 3]
------
[4, 6, 1]
[1, 8, 8]
[7, 3, 5]
------
[6, 1, 5]
[8, 8, 6]
[3, 5, 7]
------
[1, 5, 7]
[8, 6, 8]
[5, 7, 9]
------
[6, 1, 8]
[4, 7, 3]
[8, 9, 6]
------
[1, 8, 8]
[7, 3, 5]
[9, 6, 3]
------
[8, 8, 6]
[3, 5, 7]
[6, 3, 1]
------
[8, 6, 8]
[5, 7, 9]
[3, 1, 1]
------
```

I believe this would work as long as your `slice_x` and `slice_y` are smaller than the `width` and the `height` respectively. Play with the values of `slice_x` and `slice_y`, and make sure it does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[m[i][j:j+3], m[i+1][j:j+3], m[i+2][j:j+3]] for j in range(len(m[0])-2) for i in range(len(m)-2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `numpy` for this.

Numpy arrays have a function shape which would be helpful.

to convert `m` to `numpy.array`

```
import numpy as np
np_m = np.array([np.array(row) for row in m])
```

if `np_m` is converted to a numpy array then

```
row, col = np_m.shape
```

then you could iterate through each index and exclude; the first row, first col, last row and last column.

```
list_of_s = []
for r in range(1, row-1):
    for c in range(1, col-1):
        s_new = np_m[r-1:r+1][c-1:c+1]
        list_of_s.append(s_new)
```

`list_of_s` is a list (non numpy array) of all 3x3 matrices (as numpy arrays) contained within `m`

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking to the same question. I was not satisfied with the proposition as it involve big for loops. Therefore the computing time will be probably expensible as the dimention of the matrix (image increase). I came up with a solution using convolution. Therefore my loop have the dimension of the size of the sub-image. We could probably do better but here is the function. I hope it can help you :

```
import scipy
import numpy as np

def split_mat(mat,dim):
    '''
    Split one image in sub-image of dimension dim x dim
    '''
    
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            kernel=np.zeros([dim,dim])
            kernel[i,j]=1
            tmp=scipy.signal.convolve2d(mat,kernel,mode='valid').flatten()
            if i+j==0:
                nb_img=len(tmp)
                res=np.zeros([int(dim**2),nb_img])
            
            res[i*dim+j,:]=tmp
            
    return res.reshape([dim,dim,nb_img])[::-1,::-1,:]
```

You can test it like this :

```
mat=np.random.random([100,100])
dim=5
sp_mat=split_mat(mat,dim)
# The extracted matrix number i is visible by :
sp_mat[:,:,i]
```